# Bidirectional OneToOne relationship not symmetric for save?

Tags: java, jpa, orm, relation, ebean

Is there any difference between saving an entity on the owner side or on the other side if PERSIST cascade type is used on the relation?

```
@Entity
public class Slot {
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "slot", cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    private Cartridge cartridge;
}

@Entity
public class Cartridge {
    @OneToOne(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    private Slot slot;
}
```

Question:

```
slot.setCartridge(cartridge);
slot.save();
```

vs.

```
cartridge.setSlot(slot)
cartridge.save();
```

slot.save() or cartridge.save() don't seem to be the same...

both entites are already saved. I just wanted to set the relation between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cartridge owns the relationship, that means the cartridge.slot value must be set for the foreign key to be updated in most providers.  The JPA spec also states that you should maintain both sides of a bidirectional relationship to keep them in synch with what is in the database -so if your setCartridge is not setting the other side of the relationship somehow as well, when you next read the cartrige, it may not have a slot set.  JPA did away with relationship maintanace from the old EJB spec, making entities behave more like regular java objects as much as possible.

You should call something like:

```
slot.setCartridge(cartridge);
cartridge.setSlot(slot)
```

And then save on either slot or cartridge - it doesn't mater since the merge will cascade to the referenced object in either direction.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, JPA is probably working as Chris has stated, that is, you should keep the relationship up to date yourself by setting both sides at the same time.

However, IMHO it is preferrable to prevent this issue by restricting the API. *The setter should be implemented only on the relationship owner side.* This way there is no means to change the values from the other side which will be ignored by the ORM anyway.

In your current example this means Cartridge should implement the `setSlot()` method and Slot should not have the `setCartridge()` method. (Though, you had probably done better making slot the owner.)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, there is one difference. When you save the the entity using parent object, **it inserts the parent entity first and then assigns the generated key to the child before saving the child.**

It will not be the same when you save the child entity first.

Comment: @LeventeHolló: When you say, its not same, what difference you notice? Also, which object is having the mapping column(foreign key value)?