# One to many relationship doesn't work Spring boot jpa

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to create an app using spring boot for practicing my java skills, but I faced with small and stupid problem. I created one to many relationship with **UserEntity** and **LessonEntity**. And when I try to add lesson to **UserEntity** set - nothing is happening. The relation doesn't work.

Here's my code:

**UserEntity.java**

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "users", schema = "working")
@Getter @Setter
public class UserEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String patronymic;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String phoneNumber;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String state;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "teacher", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<LessonEntity> lessons;
}
```

**LessonEntity.java**

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "lessons", schema = "working")
@Getter @Setter
public class LessonEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "teacher_id")
    private UserEntity teacher;
}
```

And here's the code, where I try to add lesson to user:

```java
public void singUpForLesson(UserEntity user, SingUpForLessonModel singUpForLessonModel)
 throws UserNotFoundException {
        UserEntity teacher = userRepo.findById(singUpForLessonModel.getTeacherId()).orElseThrow(UserNotFoundException::new);
        LessonEntity lesson = new LessonEntity();
        teacher.getLessons().add(lesson);
        lessonRepo.save(lesson);
        userRepo.save(teacher);
    }
```

And here's what I see after saving teacher and lesson:

[image]

So what can be the problem? If you know, please tell me, I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: check this resource [onetomany-association](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/)

Comment: Here's a very nice answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28826374/6067302

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13514760/bidirectional-onetoone-relationship-not-symmetric-for-save

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a bidirectional relationship you have possibly contradicting information about the state of your relation ship.

This is actually the case in your scenario: The `UserEntity` has a additional `LessonEntity`, but the `LessonEntity` doesn't have a properly set `teacher` attribute.

You tell JPA with the `mappedBy` attribute which one to use.
This you set to `teacher`, i.e. `LessonEntity.teacher` which is still empty.

To fix this set the `teacher` attribute in your `LessonEntity` properly.

You can do this manually, in the setter, and I believe Hibernate has a feature to do this automatically for you.

The alternative, which I would prefer is to not have bidirectional relationships at all.

Comment: Thank you so much for explanation. Now I understand everything!